# Lower 5V output to 2V max

Tags: arduino

I am using a 5V 40 mA (max current) output on an Arduino to turn on (5V) or off (0V) as laser driver. The laser driver requires a max voltage of 2V to turn it on and flips at 0.8V. How can I lower the 5V to 2V for the driver?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They've got 200 Watt Arduino's now? That's astonishing. I was expecting milliwatts.  More seriously, the question critically depends on the power demands. Oh, and it's not software so it's off-topic here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about electronics (try our sister site)

Comment: A max voltage of 2V? Are you sure that isn't a min high voltage of 2V, because that sounds suspiciously like a TTL input.

Comment: I think you need to be clearer about a) what you are doing and b) what you are using. Please show schematics and links to datasheets for parts used.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are reading the specification of the laser driver circuit incorrectly.  It would help if you can either post the exact specifications of the driver *or* post a link to a web page that describes the driver.  Please don't link to a PDF file - most people won't download a file to view it.

I strongly suspect that the laser driver circuit wants to see a TTL-compatible signal.  I'm inferring that from the 0.8V 'flip' voltage that you mention as well as the '2V max to turn it on'.  What that means is that the driver needs a voltage HIGHER than 2.0 Vdc to turn it ON and a voltage LESS than 0.8 Vdc to guarantee that it turns OFF.

If I am correct, you don't need to anything except connect the Arduino output pin directly to the control input pin on the laser driver circuit.

Be sure to also connect your Arduino ground to the laser power supply ground.

Comment: I think you are right. It is Vin high min. But I think the OP is long gone.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is to use an adjustable voltage regulator like [THIS](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/527) one.
Use [THIS](http://www.electronics-lab.com/articles/LM317/) site to find the value of the voltage adjustment resistor required to set the output of the LM317 to a specified level.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what kind of laser you are talking about. If it is a powerful 40A laser you will need some very beefy buck SMPS preferably deriving this 2V 40A directly from mains. If you are just using small laser diodes this should work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fd4HUY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The TL431 is a voltage reference chip emitting a 2.495V nominal voltage, and diode D1 creating a diode drop of 0.7V, leaving about 1.8V to the laser. The MOSFET is driving the laser.